# SharePoint multi line rich text field not editable

Tags: sharepoint

Has anyone had this happen to them in SP2010? This happens when some users open the NewForm.aspx, but it doesn't happen for me. Why is this happening? How can it be fixed?

TIA

[image]

Comment: Are you using SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 0):

I would bet on browser related issues.

make sure your user is using 32 bit IE and there are no errors in the console

Comment: User is using 32 bit IE 10, and there are no errors thrown. Interestingly, this field is editable in Firefox and when the browser is in compatibility mode